# x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpq.a when searching for -lpq

Tags: postgresql, docker, rust, musl

I am building the rust docker image in macOS 13.2 with M1 chip using this command:

```
docker build -f ./Dockerfile -t="reddwarf-pro/alt-server:v1.0.0" .
```

after add the diesel dependencies and PostgreSQL query code, the compile process shows error:

```
#13 267.7 error: linking with `x86_64-unknown-linux-musl-gcc` failed: exit status: 1
#13 267.7   |
#13 267.7   = note: LC_ALL="C" PATH="/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/self-contained:/root/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/musl/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin" VSLANG="1033" "x86_64-unknown-linux-musl-gcc" "-m64" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/self-contained/rcrt1.o" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/self-contained/crti.o" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/self-contained/crtbeginS.o" "/tmp/rustc5Mcvhy/symbols.o" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/alt_server-28ff27f1486b44ec.alt_server.86051ab6-cgu.0.rcgu.o" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/alt_server-28ff27f1486b44ec.alt_server.86051ab6-cgu.1.rcgu.o" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/alt_server-28ff27f1486b44ec.alt_server.86051ab6-cgu.10.rcgu.o" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/alt_server-28ff27f1486b44ec.alt_server.86051ab6-cgu.11.rcgu.o" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/alt_server-28ff27f1486b44ec.alt_server.86051ab6-cgu.12.rcgu.o" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/alt_server-28ff27f1486b44ec.alt_server.86051ab6-cgu.13.rcgu.o" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/alt_server-28ff27f1486b44ec.alt_server.86051ab6-cgu.14.rcgu.o" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/alt_server-28ff27f1486b44ec.alt_server.86051ab6-cgu.15.rcgu.o" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/alt_server-28ff27f1486b44ec.alt_server.86051ab6-cgu.2.rcgu.o" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/alt_server-28ff27f1486b44ec.alt_server.86051ab6-cgu.3.rcgu.o" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/alt_server-28ff27f1486b44ec.alt_server.86051ab6-cgu.4.rcgu.o" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/alt_server-28ff27f1486b44ec.alt_server.86051ab6-cgu.5.rcgu.o" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/alt_server-28ff27f1486b44ec.alt_server.86051ab6-cgu.6.rcgu.o" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/alt_server-28ff27f1486b44ec.alt_server.86051ab6-cgu.7.rcgu.o" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/alt_server-28ff27f1486b44ec.alt_server.86051ab6-cgu.8.rcgu.o" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/alt_server-28ff27f1486b44ec.alt_server.86051ab6-cgu.9.rcgu.o" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/alt_server-28ff27f1486b44ec.20ebvhy4usycvej.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-L" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps" "-L" "/app/target/release/deps" "-L" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/zstd-sys-f78997440b0086ca/out" "-L" "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu" "-L" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/openssl-sys-97b38262ae9d4a5c/out/openssl-build/install/lib" "-L" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-f7f2e77e4dd5019d/out" "-L" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/librust_wheel-01b6aeb569dd802f.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libreqwest-235268cafa3b8706.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libhyper_tls-0263de4cf700604b.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libipnet-347aba992484a737.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libtokio_native_tls-db14dd99b2c75d8e.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libnative_tls-0bacc245d55d378d.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libopenssl_probe-cebc89b8278e1541.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libopenssl-0fbf4103afeaabcb.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libforeign_types-1331d2176c520a9b.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libforeign_types_shared-0d8c5f4773b89c76.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libopenssl_sys-6716bad431a9b551.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libbase64-117931af221b322b.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libconfig-c8c6049c62b7d7af.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libini-74ef511476013084.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libserde_hjson-d62a4b15b1d3bd91.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libserde-93ae96608b1bd379.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libnum_traits-ce7610f159b626fd.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libyaml_rust-35381d18a444d765.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/liblinked_hash_map-dfdee78171ef793d.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libtoml-4229173b0b20cc5d.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/liblazy_static-bf405a41773c9f0d.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libnom-0437770b3a4ec9e1.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/liblexical_core-b0a5974911489863.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libstatic_assertions-846a1f253bc823ae.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libarrayvec-66c550c40c686f69.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libthiserror-5188205c28cd5953.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libredis-9890167878f4fb1b.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libsha1-dfa25767a41ea1c5.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libsha1_smol-f5c0d3e390feb2f4.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libcombine-639f7d91c679a26c.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libenv_logger-360b5c6f0ca717e1.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libatty-1b72dbb8869835cf.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libtermcolor-17d08467edcc0fcd.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libhumantime-2246b224d2afa87e.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libdotenv-3cf1b93adb5e605d.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libdata_encoding-79e07a53dd957b53.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libring-dc0d9ab8d2843418.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libspin-808ba0e313cbb935.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libuntrusted-e6d54fce91ba3b0e.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/librocket_okapi-7fbda595a2fd822f.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libokapi-58cffe4f88f0f731.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libschemars-32a82360d8051c21.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libdyn_clone-5fd3968e4caa1f9b.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libuuid-b348fad58ee50f08.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/librocket-056e546acf0efa82.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libtempfile-6ae18350a0a2afe7.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libfastrand-422b421ba64667d0.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/librustix-970fa264756c0ed7.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libio_lifetimes-cca95f75291f9146.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/liblinux_raw_sys-acafcb266dae1a03.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/librocket_http-d4597dcb76d1311c.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libcookie-7efefa56979d6d5d.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libstable_pattern-286712e9dea7e892.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libref_cast-176f9ba775327aa9.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libhyper-b2d66a90e017430f.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libwant-d4f4eed86039c091.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libtry_lock-1f9824a5298bb83a.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libtower_service-7a2e9944e82fdc8e.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libhttp_body-87752f2b59328069.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libmulter-298bb1eec6caa1bf.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libspin-a67bd9a9b548f66c.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libeither-78912ab7ede94e52.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libtokio_stream-572d1297605c3ec6.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libatomic-721734aad0e87d27.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libstate-fd6ad47fb16ec29d.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libubyte-8873a8928edd2bc3.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libis_terminal-3d5926918484e985.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/librustix-1eebac23edf1b9a5.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/liblinux_raw_sys-7fc119fa93fc1340.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libfigment-7d7e24a2f48c4b02.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libtoml-5a443442b847c04a.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libtoml_edit-f2a23c5e3198e7c5.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libserde_spanned-c647253297fc77dd.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libindexmap-e7c84bfebda5daef.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libequivalent-3d9a664b512d4d7d.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libhashbrown-42219bf9d65ca0bd.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libwinnow-75ede263746c9f1a.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libtoml_datetime-c7f265f051f23fbd.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libuncased-600e621128e62a2c.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libpear-2042eeddfb330b21.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libinlinable_string-4722c84eae55683e.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libfutures-3a6dc92ccad7afc6.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libasync_stream-9002c2117f97802a.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libyansi-8859103300105a1e.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libactix_web-f3ee508d38e631aa.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libcookie-54c47a9e20b53e60.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libtime-4d6670cff21f7b78.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libtime_core-de16443903dec8d2.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libahash-3141f1a7cd90b83b.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/liburl-3130d9b026a2efc5.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libidna-4f39367a6fb162c8.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libunicode_normalization-8c7489dc120afcc8.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libtinyvec-b3270a213e102939.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libtinyvec_macros-0c8472a96b0e6057.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libunicode_bidi-b5e940cd3005675e.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libserde_urlencoded-15c8d1d58fb05e47.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libform_urlencoded-6aeac72e6c9ea07e.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libactix_server-cd13bdb6667bdf68.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libactix_router-45fbdb3d3a3d8b67.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libregex-67de13f4c09a2344.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libaho_corasick-9296a781e40a734c.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libregex_syntax-1930fff7fcde21f6.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libactix_http-0808ed9b5b53f16a.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/librand-86ef74d7fc895486.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/librand_chacha-f6d759a82cca5527.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libppv_lite86-4d4278b6655f8ac7.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/librand_core-db621243d5c27029.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libhttparse-6d700380bb951578.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libbrotli-6627d94b7ebc95d2.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libbrotli_decompressor-5b658a7be4ff1f6d.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/liballoc_stdlib-bb06483f9e9449ae.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/liballoc_no_stdlib-733fcf97255d6de6.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libhttpdate-46ca7a0bf1e58f90.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libsha1-328fbfbff93c861d.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libcpufeatures-4959be6e8fd78708.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libdigest-425d38eb704654fe.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libblock_buffer-d3e02d83b1362912.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libcrypto_common-dc5f1dda42f34f6e.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libgeneric_array-b2b373375299a0b6.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libtypenum-bd019d63c62e808e.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libbase64-dd204989e045dadc.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/liblocal_channel-8b06fa695b53dc72.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libbytestring-d80d70c1f412d7f2.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libencoding_rs-b0f77e4c0ec6f775.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/liblanguage_tags-8599cf546082200f.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libahash-63724b25b7ed5c5c.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libgetrandom-c4a2e946d82380c5.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libmime-a7c29bb2f6a7bb92.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libpercent_encoding-de131a6cd4b54640.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libh2-9eccd21b68727367.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libindexmap-29004380c32b7b29.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libhashbrown-c49a2c4892ab1ec7.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libfutures_util-63841f0bc163747a.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libfutures_io-3d5077166dd88025.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libslab-e89a44b2ebde1a56.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libfutures_channel-16fd0e5800206cce.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libfutures_task-a39bd99bd317f53b.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libpin_utils-237d04d65efee06e.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libzstd-af10b9ed89aec883.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libzstd_safe-851bab134edc3a16.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libzstd_sys-13f671e639cec254.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libflate2-0b3e00cbf6516d4f.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libminiz_oxide-9b642fb20aea30ac.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libadler-d6ef193ad4ce3618.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libcrc32fast-db5fe9cd9718597f.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libactix_service-4c5c5a2a45c34c59.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libactix_codec-d7c6db8d2f1f4d92.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libtokio_util-39d2fd0befd44fc1.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libtracing-9dce74f2c7e60223.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libtracing_core-35c270400a1c3b2d.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libonce_cell-e278bf9fcc747e5e.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libmemchr-6abe7e97fbf589bf.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libfutures_sink-ee0828df874be077.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libbitflags-4566674e0e189497.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libactix_utils-469075a79658d7bc.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/liblocal_waker-6405b41e8ba4bfeb.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libactix_rt-7e0be1b6b0fd14d2.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libtokio-4a77599513d377d4.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libsignal_hook_registry-e6ed41b81d1236b7.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libnum_cpus-d52c71496aa06c92.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libsocket2-3fa6391069d34ddf.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libmio-42f923dbac2dd597.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/liblog-2d617a0af23f5f1a.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libparking_lot-e763d1c2641009bd.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libparking_lot_core-d424ce14e2e8a102.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libcfg_if-73ba77029e651a65.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libsmallvec-45ab21e52dd33805.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/liblock_api-6a75d03bcca0eae5.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libscopeguard-1e8cf4fb1b3e72f4.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libpin_project_lite-a6e5542da4110add.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libfutures_core-601a9f36bce0e4c2.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libhttp-38697b45d1101ffa.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libbytes-5b5076928d8beede.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libfnv-5f2a9bb9bfd15be0.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libdiesel-337c511070d979d1.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libbitflags-3ac044f46f29c0de.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libbyteorder-d20298a727273977.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libpq_sys-0855362c04740c2d.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libserde_json-fb22ad7cd0c20633.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libryu-eb24e4c5cf3d6d93.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libitoa-fdc5e47068050d38.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libserde-103e90de94523e34.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libchrono-cb2b7155d06c5774.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libnum_traits-d6bd06bcb2ac84d4.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libiana_time_zone-119b79ddc85e2db7.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libtime-869733eb8718761c.rlib" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/liblibc-a10192deb3860f46.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libstd-a9e9fdf6bd876a9c.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libpanic_unwind-9916a49f714358b5.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libobject-7c95a8771a218fe4.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libmemchr-3c65c0c83cf6c411.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libaddr2line-ce480adcfb4c499a.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libgimli-9bcfb39999c11ef2.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/librustc_demangle-9bf53e18f8bef2e1.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libstd_detect-9a4ef6243d492215.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libhashbrown-529ae92fb3c6744a.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libminiz_oxide-78298b69f5703e62.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libadler-ade0c67529f3c0af.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-84e233915e97cb9e.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libunwind-7160ae02eff3b4cd.rlib" "-lunwind" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libcfg_if-edfb0a83a752acf9.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/liblibc-874d27a1db360080.rlib" "-lc" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/liballoc-2c943eba15e5e78b.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-c29380f4766b919c.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libcore-81996ce6d2f33980.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libcompiler_builtins-1fcb8ee8de54bbff.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lpq" "-Wl,--eh-frame-hdr" "-Wl,-z,noexecstack" "-nostartfiles" "-L" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib" "-L" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/self-contained" "-o" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/alt_server-28ff27f1486b44ec" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-static-pie" "-Wl,-z,relro,-z,now" "-Wl,-O1" "-nodefaultlibs" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/self-contained/crtendS.o" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/self-contained/crtn.o"
#13 267.7   = note: /usr/local/musl/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.a when searching for -lc
#13 267.7           /usr/local/musl/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpq.so when searching for -lpq
#13 267.7           /usr/local/musl/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpq.a when searching for -lpq
#13 267.7           /usr/local/musl/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lpq
#13 267.7           collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
#13 267.7           
#13 267.7 
#13 267.7 error: could not compile `alt-server` (bin "alt-server") due to previous error
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c cargo build --release --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl]: exit code: 101
```

I have treid to install the dependencies in docker build process like this:

```
RUN sudo apt-get update && apt-get install libssl-dev pkg-config musl-tools libpq5 libpq-dev -y
```

what should I do to fixed this issue? this is the full docerfile:

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE=messense/rust-musl-cross:x86_64-musl

# Our first FROM statement declares the build environment.
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE} AS builder

# Add our source code.
WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl

RUN sudo apt-get update && apt-get install libssl-dev pkg-config musl-tools libpq5 libpq-dev -y

# Build our application.
RUN cargo build --release --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl

FROM gcr.io/distroless/static-debian11
LABEL maintainer="jiang@gmail.com"
WORKDIR /app
ENV ROCKET_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
# ENV ROCKET_PORT=11014
#
# only copy the execute file to minimal the image size
# do not copy the release folder
COPY --from=builder /app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/alt-server /app/
CMD ["./alt-server"]
```

Comment: Do you have an M1 mac? Are you deliberately trying to build for an Intel platform?

Comment: yes. I am using M1 mac. And build rust app run in Ubuntu X86_64.

Comment: I don't think it is running in an x86 VM. The paths clearly all mention aarch64 which is ARM.